# Coldfusion Word Document Table - Keep With Next

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word, html-table, page-break

I am building a report that outputs the information into a word document using Coldfusion. Some of the information is output into tables and occasionally the table is occurring at the bottom of a page and the table ends up breaking apart to two pages.  How do I keep the table from breaking apart?

The format is .doc.

```
    <cfsavecontent variable="myDocument">
    <html xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
    <head>
    <xml>
    <w:WordDocument>
    <w:View>Print</w:View>
    <w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
    <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
    </w:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    </head>
    <body>

   <!--- run some queries to get information --->
   <!--- Display some information via normal <cfoutput> --->
   <!--- Then display information in table like this --->
   <cfset xtest_count = 0>
   <cfloop query="test">

   <cfif xtest_count eq 0>
   <cfset xtest_count = xtest_count + 1>
   <b><u>Speaker<cfif test.recordcount gt 1>s</cfif></u></b><br><br>
   <table width="100%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=2 border=1>
   <tr>
   <td><b>Title</b></td>
   <td><b>Name</b></td>
   <td><b>Credentials</b></td>      
   <td><b>Organization</b></td>
   </tr>
   </cfif>
   <tr>
   <td>#test.title#</td>
   <td nowrap>#test.first_name# #test.last_name#</td>
   <td>#test.credentials#</td>      
   <td>#test.company_name#</td>
   </tr>        
   </cfloop>
   </table>

   <!--- Display More information--->

   </body>
   </html>
   </cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Spoiler alert: We're going to need some sample code.

Comment: Ditto. Please [edit] your question to include some code - just the *minimum* necessary to reproduce the issue.  Side note, I did not down vote this, but if you are new to Stack Overflow, please take a minute to peruse the [Quick Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [What types of Questions are a good fit for S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). As written the above is too broad/lacking details, and is likely to be closed.

Comment: What exactly is the target format? .doc? .docx? .rtf? How do you perform the report generation?

Comment: Technically you are generating a faux Word document, ie HTML that MS Word can interpret.  So this issues really has nothing to do with ColdFusion.  Assuming it is possible, you should be looking for properties controlling tables and page break behavior in either standard CSS or the [MS Office Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_format).